# Money exchange in Moscow

Tags: russia, exchange, moscow

What denomination and condition of USD bills ($20, $50, $100 etc.) are most readily convertible in Moscow and is it banks or money changers that offer better exchange rates?

Comment: This is way too broad.  The exchange will take any bill.   Now as far as best exchange rate in a city of about 1000 square miles and 14 million inhabitants would be a bit broad.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes. First, I really doubt the "will take any bill" answer, I think e.g. converting $1 bills or the rare $2 bills may be a problem. Secondly, asking for a site where you can find the best exchange rates is a legitimate question, I suggested one site myself (see answer below) but I would love to know about others.

Comment: Question is perfectly fine, @Karlson. One finds good rate at http://quote.rbc.ru/cash Re: notes - $100 are most common and preferred, but be sure there are no marks or stampings.

Comment: @Großväterkämpfte You can speak for all the exchange places?  Everywhere in Moscow?  $100 is the most common and the best rate is the official exchange rate but you may not receive the official exchange rate at the place where you exchange money.  And lastly the link doesn't exist.

Comment: http://quote.rbc.ru/cash/ (fixed missing slash) @Karlson, you don't make any sense. WTH is "official exchange rate"? Who TH "receives it"? Why TH you are trying to fog the things demanding to take all really really all the shroffs into account?

Comment: @Großväterkämpfte Banks receive official exchange rate, which some of the banks pass along to their card members when used.  And when you're talking about the city of 14 million and 1000 sq.mi. you have narrow down the locations.

Comment: @Karlson, ugh, what? CBR rate? Things you are talking is simply untrue. Banks are monitoring MOEX trading session to establish their rates. It is totally impossible to **sell** USD for RUB at CBR today's rate (which is mere informative value not intended for retail forex market at all). Right now its not possible to **buy** USD for RUB at CBR today's rate as well.

Comment: @Großväterkämpfte Read my comment carefully.

Comment: @Karlson, ok, give me some of these banks to verify you weren't talking nonsense. I guess I know the answer tho...

Comment: @Großväterkämpfte Read my comment carefully.  I wasn't referring to the Cash for Cash transaction but electronic withdrawals.  And again.  Your link only shows 5 places in different areas of Moscow.   How many exchange places are there in Moscow?

Comment: @Karlson, yes. I read your nonsense. Now I'm sure about it because you are backpedaling on claims of existence of "free" (customer pays no fee, bank works for free) currency exchange either cash (you started forgetting what OP asked about cash, huh) or electronic.

Comment: @Großväterkämpfte I am not backpedaling on anything.  Question is still too broad to be acceptable.  If you want sample rates RBC or [Kovalut](http://kovalut.com/). That won't help you find best rates because they would be confined to a particular geographic area and I seriously doubt that OP or anyone else is so dedicated to finding the best rate that they may be willing to go across town just to get it.

Comment: @Karlson, well you didn't provide sample banks who "receives the official rate" and then allows customers to buy/sell foreign currency at it. That's backpedaling in my book.

Comment: Question is quite specific for ones who know about foreign currency market in Moscow, however. One foreigner seeking to sell his $1000 for RUB may pay 2-3% commission fee or 0.4-0.5% depending on the bank he chooses to carry this operation.

Comment: @Großväterkämpfte I wasn't looking for one.  And question didn't become any better.  The question needs to be narrowed geographically to a district rather than a whole city in this case.

Comment: @Karlson, Moscow is narrow enough. Anything else?

Comment: @Großväterkämpfte Nope it's not.  But you're welcome to try and reopen.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, bring crisp, new, undamaged $50 and $100 bills. You can find exchange rates on various web sites, e.g. here's a map of Moscow showing rates at various locations: http://4map.ru/ (you need to enter all your parameters on the left side, the currency pair and the amount, and then click the grey button to show the rates on the map).

Comment: Your link is interesting (however, I'm not sure if it is accurate). Re: notes - its OK to be not new and crisp, but certainly undamaged. @pnuts, no, Franklins are preferred, Jacksons are for gangsters, maybe.